# Align checkbox and label using CSS

Tags: html, css

WooCommerce outputs its checkboxes like this...

```html
<label class="checkbox ">
    <input class="input-checkbox " name="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="1" type="checkbox">
    Tick This Box
</label>
```

This results in alignment issues...

[image]

I can fix them by editing the way checkboxes are output but before I do, is there a simpler way with CSS to get them to look like this?

[image]

Comment: By default the alignment is good, it must be something else in your stylesheet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can place `checkbox` with `position: absolute`.

```css
.checkbox {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-left: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

.checkbox input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<label class="checkbox">
    <input class="input-checkbox " name="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="1" type="checkbox">
    Tick This Box
</label>
<label class="checkbox">
    <input class="input-checkbox " name="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="1" type="checkbox">
    This is a multi line label with a lot of text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Run the snippet its working perfect

```css
.checkbox {
  padding-left:10px;
  position: relative;
}

.checkbox input {
 float:left
}
```

```html
<label class="checkbox">
    <input class="input-checkbox " name="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="1" type="checkbox">
    Tick This Box
</label>
```

Comment: That is not working for multiline labels, if the screen/viewport gets too narrow.